# Foreach loop, meaning of the $index

Tags: php

```
$evens = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach ($evens as $index=>$value){

    if ($value % 2 == 0){

    echo "<br> Even numbers are :$value";
    }

}
```

Hello folks,

I am just reading about foreach loops, I'm just wondering what means this:

$evens as $index=>$value

$evens = my array
$value = random named (by me) variable that contains results
but what is $index? Is that reserved keyword in PHP or ... ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Arrays in PHP are all associative. If you don't provide the keys then they are generated starting from 0 automatically. `$evens` is exactly equivalent to `array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 5, 5 => 6)`.

Comment: See also [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: array is consist of key and value so divide $evens array into key and value and it is an easy way to  get your desired value from array.

Comment: Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) (*"what is $index? Is that reserved keyword in PHP"* -- no, it is a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)) and about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Please dont ask what `%` does without researching first.

Comment: I didn't ask what % does, I just asked for $index.
Thank you folks.